# RSA Weak key, i.e small modulus

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

Let (e,n) be a public key such that 100 < e <200 and 2000 < n < 2500. M is a message and $M^e > n$. I know that if n is small we can factorize it. Is there any method to find M without factoring n?, i.e other attacking method different than factoring for small n.

Comment: Why would you do this? Factoring $n < 2500$ is trivial, or do you mean that $n$ is a number with $2000\dots 2500$ **bits**?

Comment: n is integer, 2500 is integer. I know that Factoring n is is trivial for n < 2500.  I mean like is there any method that we can find M without factoring n.

Comment: A table of the $500\;\; \phi(n)$ values allows computing the secret exponent $d$ without factoring.

Comment: Another obvious method would be brute forcing all $d$ less than $2500.$

Comment: is there any method using log

Comment: log would solve for exponents, you could use modular roots but then you need again the factorization of $n$.

Comment: @gammatester why 500 values of $\phi(n)$?

Comment: @unseen-rider: The 499 numbers $\phi(2001), \phi(2002), \dots, \phi(2498), \phi(2499),$ with the count  rounded up to 500 :)